# redirect find items to a separate window

Tags: sublime-text-2

How do I list the lines that contains the matches from the "find" command ? ie., I would like to list all the matching lines in a separate window. Currently one can only goto next / previous 'find'. This is something like "list lines containing" option in Ultra edit. For Eg.,  I have a text file that contains lines like "c:\src..." which are filenames. I want to "find" src that will give me all the filenames, In the find command I can only goto next/previous find, what I would like is to get all the "found" items that I can copy/paste into a separate edit window that can be saved as a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can highlight the text you want to search for, then use Alt+F3 to select all occurences.
You can then use ctrl + L to expand the selection to the whole line, and ctrl+C to copy.

If you're using OSX, replace ctrl with cmd.